# Why does Views get scattered in Application while feeding data to it?

Tags: android

I am building an application wherein the user is asked to fill out a form that I have designed.The form screen looks like the fig1 
I have used scroll view for the entire screen and then relative layout as parent view which in turn contains lots of text, Edit text views.

Problem:
1) whenever the user tries feeding in the data, Like Entering username, all the views get scattered as shown in fig 2

2) Though i have used Scroll View, I am not able to scroll down the screen to see anything below DOB

Any help appreciated!

[image]
[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">


<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#3dcc24">


  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
      android:text="  User Name"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="Email Address"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:hint="Enter EmailID"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:text="Password"

      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText10"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:ems="10"

      android:hint="Enter Password"
      android:inputType="textPassword"

      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
      android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
      android:text="Phone Number"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText7"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText10"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText10"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="phone"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
      android:text="BirthDate"

      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />


  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText12"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="date"
      android:hint="DD-MM-YYYY"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


  </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add xml layout to question

Comment: @MM I have done the Edits as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3dcc24">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email Address"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter EmailID"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="396dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BirthDate"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="DD-MM-YYYY"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This works, But why doesn't relative layout work? and why do views get scattered if relative Layout is used?

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal RelativeLayout can also be used but I find LinearLayout easier to work with for layout you wanted.If you want to use RelativeLayout Remove android:fillViewport="true" from your old xml and try to fix the layout.

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal You can try with RelativeLayout if you need it for you app